# ubuntu20.04 prompt "dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)",anyone help?

Tags: apt, grub2, package-management, dpkg, udev

now i exec the update command on my box,then get some error info.
here is the output:

```
root@ubuntu20:/var/cache/apt/archives# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 grub-efi-amd64 : Depends: grub-common (= 2.04-1ubuntu26.8) but 2.04-1ubuntu26.7 is installed
 grub-efi-amd64-bin : Depends: grub-common (= 2.04-1ubuntu26.8) but 2.04-1ubuntu26.7 is installed
 grub2-common : Depends: grub-common (= 2.04-1ubuntu26.8) but 2.04-1ubuntu26.7 is installed
 initramfs-tools-core : Depends: udev but it is not installed
 ubuntu-drivers-common : Depends: udev (>= 204-0ubuntu4~) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@ubuntu20:/var/cache/apt/archives# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin cryptsetup-run dict dictzip finalrd libisns0 libmaa4 libplymouth5 librecode0 libsgutils2-2 liburcu6 recode sg3-utils
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  grub-common udev
Suggested packages:
  multiboot-doc grub-emu xorriso desktop-base
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  udev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  grub-common
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
42 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3,239 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,374 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 201798 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../udev_245.4-4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking udev (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_245.4-4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/etc/init.d/udev.dpkg-new' (while processing './etc/init.d/udev'): Operation not permitted
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../grub-common_2.04-1ubuntu26.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grub-common (2.04-1ubuntu26.8) over (2.04-1ubuntu26.7) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/grub-common_2.04-1ubuntu26.8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/etc/init.d/grub-common.dpkg-new' (while processing './etc/init.d/grub-common'): Operation not permitted
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_245.4-4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/grub-common_2.04-1ubuntu26.8_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@ubuntu20:/var/cache/apt/archives# dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_245.4-4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 201798 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../udev_245.4-4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking udev (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_245.4-4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb (--install):
 unable to create '/etc/init.d/udev.dpkg-new' (while processing './etc/init.d/udev'): Operation not permitted
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_245.4-4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb
root@ubuntu20:/var/cache/apt/archives# dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/grub-common_2.04-1ubuntu26.8_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 201798 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../grub-common_2.04-1ubuntu26.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grub-common (2.04-1ubuntu26.8) over (2.04-1ubuntu26.7) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/grub-common_2.04-1ubuntu26.8_amd64.deb (--install):
 unable to create '/etc/init.d/grub-common.dpkg-new' (while processing './etc/init.d/grub-common'): Operation not permitted
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/grub-common_2.04-1ubuntu26.8_amd64.deb
root@ubuntu20:/var/cache/apt/archives#
```

i follow the tips but dosen't work.
then googled,found no way agin,anyone help ?